# BB 10 C++ Button on click

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

In QML you can do the on click event.  I am writing my qml in C++, however there is no onclick method.

How do you get the on click to work.

```
Button *btnSave = new Button();
btnSave->setText("Save");
contentContainer->add(btnSave);
```

Does anyone have a simple example that they could provide to get me started?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in C++, you have to connect a signal (in this case, is the Button's [clicked()](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__abstractbutton.html#clicked) to a slot of your class). You better take a look [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/signals_slots/).

Supposing you defined a slot called `onSaveButtonClicked()` in your header, that will be called when your button is clicked:

```
public slots:
    void onSaveButtonClicked();
```

in your application class, after create your button, you'd have to do:

```
connect(btnSave, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onSaveButtonClicked()));
```

When your button is clicked, it will emit the signal that will call the slot function.